# .htaccess mod rewrite not doing redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to do a very basic mod rewrite on wordpress (with the default .htaccess settings). I need to redirect from category `test1` to `test2`

What I attempt fails. I think im missing something basic here

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^test1/$ test2/$ #returns 404

#alternatively this one returns 404 too: RewriteRule ^/test1/$ test2/$

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? The order is important.

Comment: Also, please include complete URLs that this redirect should match against.

Comment: @these were the very first directives, moreover those are complete directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^test1/$ test2/$ #returns 404
> ```

If mod_rewrite is enabled and you tried this exact line then you've get a 500 Internal Server Error because you have an invalid *flags* argument. You need to explicitly state that this is a redirect with the `R` flag, otherwise you'll get an *internal rewrite*.

Also, the 2nd argument to the `RewriteRule` directive is an ordinary string, not a regex, so the trailing `$` on `test2/$` is invalid.

Any external redirects must also go above the existing WordPress directives (ie. the front-controller).

Try the following instead of the above:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^test1/$ /test2/ [R=302,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# ... Rest of .htaccess file goes here
```

This redirects the single URL `/test1/` to `/test2/`.

Change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) only after you have tested that it is working OK. (That is of course only if this should be permanent.)

The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required here.

---

> alternatively this one returns 404 too: RewriteRule ^/test1/$ test2/$

That wouldn't do anything in a per-directory (`.htaccess`) context, because of the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

The fact that you are getting a 404 for the first directive suggests these directives aren't actually being processed?!

Comment: I changed the option declaration to `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` and remover `RewriteBase /` and it worked! Although the second argument is not a regexp it still started to place those `$` characters at the end of URL and before it was just 404. Thank you very much!

Comment: `Options FollowSymLinks` (no `+` or `-` prefix`) overwrites the existing setting. By prefixing `+` or `-` you are adding or removing that setting (you can't mix no-prefix with prefixed values in a single directive). Instead of the `RewriteBase` directive I prefixed the target URL with a slash (preferable for "redirects"). With regards to trailing `$`... make sure your browser cache is cleared as erroneous 301 redirects will be cached persistently by the browser.

Comment: Once again thank you for the clarification. Redirect caching is a very nasty thing for anyone who might read this comment in the future you can clear redirect cache in chrome by placing this into address bar chrome://net-internals/#events and then selecting 'Clear cache' from the menu  (opens from top-right triangle)